# Window.print() fails to print

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For printing my Aspx web page I use following code but in IE I encounter "Stack over flow at line:0"  error message and in fire fox any thing doesn't happen.
what's wrong?

```
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function print() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="toolbar" style="width:400px">
            <ul>
<li>
                <img alt="" src="../../../CssImages/printer_128.png" id="ImgPrint" width="20px" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="print()"/>
                </li>
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function:

```
function print() {
    window.print(); // <-- refers to this custom function
}
```

will put `print` into the global object as `window.print`. So in fact you're calling the function itself, which calls itself, etc. This will continue forever which causes an overflow.

Because `window.print` is already defined natively, why not eliminate the custom function? If you remove `function print() {...}` it should work fine, because it will then call the 'real' `window.print` (as `print` is just a shortcut to `window.print`), which actually does the printing.

Comment: Or at least not give it a name that will hide the function name you do want to use...

Comment: Best mistake ever. Error message was pretty descriptive though.